# Proposed Tag for configuration files which override or merge

Tags: discussion, tags

I've come up with a tag ([per-directory-settings](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/per-directory-settings/info)) for questions about configuration files that override or merge over one another based on an answer to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282547/what-are-configuration-files-that-can-be-overriden-by-existing-in-the-current-di) if you think the name of it sucks, please come up with a better one; and tag anything you think this may apply to.

Off the top of my head I can think of `.gitignore`, and the Maven2 POM.  If you come up with other ones please tag them accordingly.

Comment: When you create a tag, you should fill out the tag excerpt and wiki with information about how it should be used...

Comment: "There is no usage guidance for this tag … yet!" that the excerpt? Pls fill that before coming up with a name.

Comment: No, it has to be peer reviewed first.

Comment: While it does have to be peer reviewed it doesn't mean you can submit them for review when you create the new tag.

Answer (score 0):

No that seems redundant. If you have a question about "per directory" settings or otherwise, tag it with whatever it's about `php`, `emacs` whatever and then the next most appropriate tag `configuration`, `htaccess`, `ini`.

At best the tag is redundant.

At worst it's confusing, wastes a slot and time (in editing)

Comment: Those tags are superfluous too. Anyone with a bit of knowledge about most topics should know what files their programs use.